# JSP: tag Holder not working

Tags: java, jsp, taglib, tag-handler

I have made tld and tag holder (of type Body Tag Support) in which `src` is the required attribute.
In JSP:

```jsp
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/tld1.tld" prefix="imageViewer1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <imageViewer1:NewTagHandler src="dd"></imageViewer1:NewTagHandler>
    </body>
</html>
```

In tag handler I am only printing `src`. But I am getting no output.

In tld1.tld:

```xml
<tag>
    <name>NewTagHandler</name>
    <tag-class>taghandler.NewTagHandler</tag-class>
    <body-content>JSP</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <name>src</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        <type>java.lang.String</type>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

In taghandler.NewTagHandler

```
@Override
public int doAfterBody() throws JspException {
    try {
        BodyContent bodyCont = getBodyContent();
        JspWriter out = bodyCont.getEnclosingWriter();
        out.println(src);
        writeTagBodyContent(out, bodyCont);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        handleBodyContentException(ex);
    }

    if (theBodyShouldBeEvaluatedAgain()) {
        return EVAL_BODY_AGAIN;
    } else {
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you printing the content of `src`?

Comment: Could you provide the code that handles your custom tag?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i have posted it.

Comment: @M.S. can you post the code for `taghandler.NewTagHandler`?

Comment: I see you are using `getBodyContent()` but your tag body is empty (in the sample code above).  Is that intentional?